# Windows 10 - cannot change the user name folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-profiles

I wanted to rename folder C:\Users\Myname in Windows 10.

1. I renamed Users folder in Registry Editor
2. Used netplwiz - and changed name there as well.

After that restarted Pc, now i'm login to temp account, where i should rename it manually and when i try rename it gives me:

> The action cannot be completed because the file is open in other
>   program

What can i do in this situation?

Comment: Tried a System Restore rollback?

Comment: @w32sh no i didn't tried, how it can help?

Comment: SR would rollback your registry hives, which means your original profile directory path in the registry will be restored.

Comment: @w32sh but i need to change this profile name, and i was following steps how to do it, and on the last step, i faced with this problem where i need to rename manually the User folder

Comment: Changing profile folder path/name would involve [changing hundreds of registry keys](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/rename-user-profile-folder-windows/) (not just the `ProfileImagePath` registry value)and probably the folder Permissions, if you want to make sure no applications break. Best option is to create a new local account with the preferred name, and transfer your data.

Comment: @w32sh  Ok, thank you, i will try this

Comment: When creating a new account, create a local account instead of Microsoft. Once logged in, you can switch to MS account if needed. This way the folder name won't be truncated to 5 characters.